# What is an IMAGEWTY firmware format?

Tags: android, android-rom

I'm trying customize the ROM of my very old tablet, but there is no stock ROMs in any other format than `.img` | 
`ls -l:`

`r 0 0 605M Jun 30  2015 M100-8312-8723bs-0312+2145-FWT-0266-v0.8.img`

How do I unpack it ? (debian)

Comment: .img is just like a .iso, they contain burnable data that can replace another container of data (chips, cds) probably you  got the firmware itself, try to burn it to a cd and check the files you want to alter

Comment: No, it is not iso or udf or something like this. Look at he EDIT#1, I've added header information.

Comment: https://github.com/Ithamar/awutils/blob/master/imagewty.h

Comment: Why do they downvote the question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**IMAGEWTY** is an Allwinner A10 devices firmware format. There is [awutils](https://github.com/Ithamar/awutils) intended to work with this format.

Comment: But I've no idea how to work with unpacked files yet, but it is answer to the question about the format :)

Comment: Clone that repo, run `make awimage` to build the tool, then `awimage path/to/firmware.img` to unpack all files.